# How to Compare values between rows in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table `table1` like below. I want to find all `H` in `Status` field that is in between two `L`. The output for mentioned criteria should be `04/01/15`, `05/01/15` and `07/01/15`. How can I solve this?

```
Date          Status
01/01/15        A
02/01/15        H
03/01/15        L
04/01/15        H
05/01/15        H
06/01/15        L
07/01/15        H
08/01/15        L
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.Date, t.Status
FROM 
    yourTable AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(Date) AS minDate, Max(Date) AS maxDate
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Status = 'L') AS l
ON t.Date >= l.minDate
    AND t.Date <= l.maxDate
    AND t.Status <> 'L';
```

Comment: @FakhrulMahdi If you want to detect a status between two different statuses It is another question and you can ask another question ;).