# How to compare values within a same field in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table 'table1' like below. I want to find all H in Status field that is in between two L. The output for mentioned criteria should be 03/07/15, 08/07/15 and 09/07/15. How can I solve this?

```
date      Status
01/07/15    A
02/07/15    L
03/07/15    H
04/07/15    L
05/07/15    H
06/07/15    A
07/07/15    L
08/07/15    H
09/07/15    H
10/07/15    L
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942892/how-to-compare-values-between-rows-in-access-query

Comment: Not same but similar.....

Comment: So you should add the SQL from the answer there and explain which case it doesn't handle, so we can build upon it.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select date, status from table1 where status = 'H' and date  between (select MIN(date) from table1 where status = 'L') and (select MAX(date) from table1 where status = 'L')
```

Comment: This won't work because it only looks at the global MAX and MIN date with status L.